# Show that a parabola passes through the point (0,1)

Tags: analysis, geometry, coordinate-systems

Let $y=x^2+ax+b$ be a parabola that cuts the coordinate axes at three distinct points. Show that the circle passing through these three points also passes through $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$, $B$ be the points of intersection of the parabola with the $x$ axis , $C$ the point of intersection with the $y$ axis, $D$ the point of intersection of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ with the $y$ axis and $O$ the origin. Since $ACBD$ is concyclic, $\triangle AOC \sim \triangle DOB$, so $OD = \dfrac{AO \cdot OB}{OC}$. Now looking at the equation $x^2 + ax + b$, $AO \cdot OB$ is the product of the roots and $OC = b$, so by vieta  formulas $OD = 1$ as desired.

Comment: But, it only proves that the point is $(0,\pm1)$ not exactly $(0,1)$.

Comment: Oh yeah, but just note that $D$ cannot lie between $O$ and $C$ as then it would be inside the triangle $ABC$.

Comment: Yeah. But, does that help? I mean, we don't know whether $C$ has a negative or positive ordinate.

Comment: The coeff. of $x^2$ is positive, the parabola opens upward, if $C$ had a positive abscissa then it would not intersect the $x$ axis.

Comment: Ooo. I just missed that. Anyway, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You may find the three distinct points first by solving quadratic equations. Then there is a circle passing through the three points, namely, $x^2 + y^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$. By substituting the three points into the circle, $D$, $E$ and $F$ can be solved by linear equations. Then you may check whether the point $(0,1)$ lies on the circle.

Answer (score 1):

The points are
$$\{(x_1\mid y_1);(x_2\mid y_2);(x_3\mid y_3)$$
If
$$\begin{vmatrix}
x_1^2+y_1^2&x_1&y_1&1\\
x_2^2+y_2^2&x_2&y_2&1\\
x_3^2+y_3^2&x_3&y_3&1\\
1&0&1&1
\end{vmatrix}=0\;$$,
then $(0\mid 1)\;$ is concyclic with the other points.
For your parabola, the pertinent points are
$$\{\left(\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}2\mid 0\right);\left(\frac{-a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}2\mid 0\right);(0\mid b)\}$$
and the corresponding determinant is

$$\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{2a^2-4b-2a\sqrt{a^2-4b}}4&\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}2&0&1\\
\frac{2a^2-4b+2a\sqrt{a^2-4b}}4&\frac{-a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}2&0&1\\
b^2&0&b&1\\
1&0&1&1
\end{vmatrix}\;$$.

No matter what the values of $a$ and $b$ -- even if the parabola does not intersect with the x-axis -- the determinant always vanishes! So when the parabola DOES intersect the x-axis, the points are concyclic.

Comment: Yeah. But, I believe it'll be quite troublesome to check the same given the equation.